# Canvas performance against simple html+css titles

Tags: html, optimization, canvas

Since this morning I have been trying to convert my `h2`,`h1` html titles into images using the `html` canvas. But I wonder if this is a good idea or not!

We know images are heavy when they are to be rendered from the server to the client. But they can bring fluidity and best effect rather than htmls.

My question is to know if locally created images(canvas/svg) are good than simple htmls ?

This

```
    var c = document.getElementById("h1Title");
   var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
   ctx.font = "30px Arial";
   ctx.fillText("Hello World",10,50);
```

Against this

```
   <h1 style='font:30px Arial;left:10px;top:50px'>Hello World</h1>
```

Comment: My 2-cents: Don't reinvent the wheel:  Use html elements when you can and canvas when you need canvas's unique capabilities.

Comment: Have you heard of cuffon ? I think it does it

Answer (score 1):

It is not good idea.

Locally created `<canvas>` elements are not as good as stylized `<h1>` and similar elements

- Normal HTML elements provide easy styling using CSS. With CSS3 transforms you can do very complex text styling. E.g. http://www.css3maker.com/text-rotation.html - if you have any specific effect in mind which you think cannot be achieved with CSS3 please open a separate question for this effect
- Normal HTML elements are hardware accelerated and there is often performance penalty rendering text through `<canvas>`
- User interaction (text selection, copy paste, arrow navigation and accessibility) is ruined with `<canvas>`